# ASP.NET ReportViewer Skinning

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

Is it possible to skin the contents of a ReportViewer generated report (such as tables, headers, etc), so that it fits in with the page style?

Side note: It's only the colouring of the report components that I'm interested in.

Comment: What kind of reports are we talking about rdl, rdlc, crystal something else?

Comment: Are you using SQL reporting services?

Comment: We were using SSRS, but now I'm moving the reports out of there and into intranet pages to be rendered using the ASP.NET 2.0 ReportViewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can style the reports.  Each report item will have a set of properties, such as borders, background color, foreground color, font, background-image, hyperlink, etc...

Depending on the report item, some have more properties than others.  You can make reportviewer look good in any app.  If you need to customize the menu bar, you will need to create your own.

Comment: Yup, I know I can apply the formatting per-component, but is it possible to apply via a stylesheet?

Comment: No.  This is not an option, as the reportviewer control is generated with inline CSS.  In my opinion, Microsoft dropped the ball here.

Comment: Just a side note.. If you really wanted to accomplish this, you would need to create multiple RDLC files, one for each desired style.